# What does this java function do?

Tags: java, zip

I'm using WebAnno, and I'm trying to get a zip file I created imported as a project, but I keep getting an error because the zip is invalid. 
Exporting a project from WebAnno creates a zip file, that is valid when I import it back. But when I unzip it, then re-zip it, it is slightly different and doesn't get recognized as valid by WebAnno.
I found the function that tests the validity in the source code, but I don't understand what exactly it is testing for with the zip file.

```
public static boolean isZipValidWebanno(File aZipFile)
        throws IOException
    {

        boolean isZipValidWebanno = false;
        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(aZipFile);
        for (Enumeration zipEnumerate = zip.entries(); zipEnumerate.hasMoreElements();) {
            ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) zipEnumerate.nextElement();
            if (entry.toString().replace("/", "").startsWith(ImportUtil.EXPORTED_PROJECT)
                    && entry.toString().replace("/", "").endsWith(".json")) {
                isZipValidWebanno = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isZipValidWebanno;
}
```

Comment: The code checks if one of the entries (=files) in the zip file starts with `ImportUtil.EXPORTED_PROJECT` (whatever that is) and ends with `.json`. But since it's not clear what `entry.toString()` returns, it's not safe to say if the file name (or anything else) is used for that comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The typical mistake when re-packing a WebAnno project archive is to include a top-level folder in the ZIP archive.

A proper [WebAnno project archive](https://webanno.github.io/webanno/releases/3.5.7/docs/user-guide.html#sect_projects_export) has a structure along the lines of:

```
+- <project ID>.json - project metadata file
+- annotation
|  +- <source document name>
|     +- <user ID>.XXX - file representing the annotations for this user in the selected format.
+- annotation_ser
|  +- <source document name>
|     +- <user ID>.ser - serialized CAS file representing the annotations for this user
+- curation
|  +- <source document name>
|     +- CURATION_USER.XXX - file representing the state of curation in the selected format.
|     +- CORRECTION_USER.XXX - correction project: original document state, automation project automatically generated suggestions
curation_ser
+- <source document name>
|  +- CURATION_USER.ser - serialized UIMA CAS representing the state of curation
|  +- CORRECTION_USER.ser - correction project: original document state, automation project automatically generated suggestions
+- log
|  +- <project ID>.log - project log file
+- source - folder containing the original source files
```

The typical mistake is that people extract such an archive and the extraction tool creates a folder to put all the contents in. When re-packaging, users tend to include this folder into the re-packaged archive. This results in a structure such as:

```
+- SOME FOLDER NAME
   +- <project ID>.json
   +- annotation
   .  +- ...
   .
```

WebAnno won't import such archives. Make sure that the re-packaged archive does *not* include an additional top-level folder.

*Disclosure: I am the maintainer of WebAnno*